# Do pauli matrices form a lie algebra?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I have a doubt relative to pauli matrices and lie algebras, beause i have seen usually that we get the Lie algebra for $SO(2)$, the pauli matrices in this form,
$$
i\frac{\sigma_i }{2} \quad \text{for the commutator being} \quad \left[i\frac{\sigma_i}{2},i\frac{\sigma_j}{2}\right]=i\varepsilon_{ijk}\frac{\sigma_k}{2}
$$

And i dont know why is this basis usually chosen. I have understood that the $1/2$ is there for the trace to be $1$, and this basis is a Lie algebra of $SO(2)$.

- If we get a basis with the Pauli matrices without the $i$ factor, only $\sigma_i$, is that a Lie algebra? Because you can still use it to make representations.
- Is the condition of the commutator being $\left[i\frac{\sigma_i}{2},i\frac{\sigma_j}{2}\right]=i\varepsilon_{ijk}\frac{\sigma_k}{2}$ needed to be a Lie algebra?

I searched but i didnt find any theorem or rule to follow to corrobore if a basis is a valid Lie algebra. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Probably this is partly just to make things simple: Writing $\Gamma_i:=i \sigma_i/2$, we have $[\Gamma_i,\Gamma_j]=\epsilon_{ijk}\Gamma_k$. If either $i$ or $2$ were excluded, then they'd end up in the above statement instead.